# Why are heat-shields on re-entry vehicles smooth and not textured to increase drag?

Tags: thermodynamics, velocity, space, meteorites

Meteorites naturally texture themselves via the formation of *regmaglypts*, 'thumbprint-shaped' indentations caused by ablation of their surface, during entry into the atmosphere.

This appears to naturally increase atmospheric drag on them, see exploding rocky meteors over Russia for more details.

Would a more textured surface on an artificial re-entry vehicle thus be more beneficial?

Is this not the point of the re-entry system, to 'exchange speed for heat' and thus lose enough velocity to enable the deployment of cheap parachutes earlier, giving more control over landing, landing orientation and choice of landing site?

Comment: Could it be that you don't want your spacecraft to explode like a rocky meteor? Interesting question though.

Comment: I noticed I had implied that... oops, but I meant that meteors tumble uncontrollably, while a re-entry vehicle could guide the way it presents itself to the air-flow... and not mechanically stress itself in ways that lead to an 'explosive event on re-entry'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heat shields do not experience flow across them.  There is a hyper-compressed layer of atmosphere next to the shield, which (due to said compression) gets very hot.  The atmospheric flow is external to this compression layer, so there's no value to a roughened surface.

Now, keep in mind that the original concept for the Space Shuttle was a monolithic heatshield for the entire fuselage.  It turned out impossible to fabricate the material in large shapes, which is why the cost skyrocketed (sorry) and a zillion separate tiles had to be installed, inspected, and the gaps filled w/ other special stuff. The roughness here was not by design but by necessity of manufacture.

Comment: I'm assuming the heat-shield experiences substantial mechanical forces due to the deceleration it provides to the craft behind it which are related to the pressure of the layer of plasma/gases at its surface. The material (silicon aerogels? carbon-carbon?) must be mechanically tough enough to resist these forces too... so limiting the choices of material!

Comment: ""Heat shields do not experience flow across them."" This is wrong! If You were right, the initially compressed layer would cool down and no heat at all would reach the shield afterwards.

Comment: @georg : My statement is that there is no active physical flow of air molecules. Did you mean to state that there is a flow of energy thru that layer (which is certainly true)?

Comment: No, I meant that there is a flow of hot air adjacent to the heat shield.

Comment: @Georg then I'll have to ask for citations.  that's inconsistent with what I've read.